# Use WordPress's Media Uploader/ Manager in non WordPress php application

Tags: php, uploads, javascript

I need a image upload and browse, resize, crop functionalities.
Since it is already built available in wp. I need some idea how can i use it my custom php application **Laravel**.

Adding the media manager's js file, configure it.
listing file with json API.

If you could help me figure out which all js/php files i have to look to.